# How to properly use Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) to declare classes?

Tags: javascript, scope, iife

I understand there are many different ways to declare an IIFE: 
(http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

But what I can't understand is how sometimes many classes are defined within the same IIFE, and other times they are separated in each their own.

Example:

## This...

```
(function(scope) {
  var ClassA = scope.ClassA = function(params) {
    this.params = params;
  }

  var ClassB = scope.ClassB = function(params) {
    this.params = params;
  }
})(someNamespace || window);
```

## VS. That...

```
(function(scope) {
    var ClassA = scope.ClassA = function(params) {
        this.params = params;
    }
})(someNamespace || window);

(function(scope) {
    var ClassB = scope.ClassB = function(params) {
        this.params = params;
    }
})(someNamespace || window);
```

Are there any advantages to isolate each classes into their own IIFE?

Comment: As they are written there is no difference.

Comment: And those aren't really classes, just variables ?

Comment: @adeneo Sorry for the improper lingo (is it a prototype definition?), I'm coming from a different programming language background.

Answer (score 3):

The point of using an IIFE is to stop variables used by one piece of code leaking into places where they might get mixed up with identically named variables used by another piece of code.

If the two functions should share variables, then putting them in the same IIFE is a good idea. If not, then they should be kept separate to avoid naming collisions and to show to the maintainer that they are separate.

Comment: Performance-wise, are there any advantages to seal each class / prototype definitions (does it help the VM in some way to lookup variables / functions only within the scope of the IIFE)? I'm guessing these would be negligible amounts, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Any difference would be negligible. Write code that is easy to maintain before you start thinking about performance hacks. When you do have a performance issue, then benchmark code to find bottlenecks and focus on them. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Answer (score 1):

There are *slight* performance advantages to sharing the IIFE. 
I put your two examples into jsperf and compared them, and the shared IIFE runs *slightly* faster....but the performance gains are totally negligible unless you are declaring many thousands of classes in this way.

http://jsperf.com/iife-performance-for-class

Here's a different test comparing IIFE performance in a slightly different manner:
http://jsperf.com/iife-performance

I prefer to put each class in its own file so that it's easier to find each class during the editing process, which would result in each class getting its own IIFE.

Comment: No one cares about the performance of a class *definition*. We only care about instances, their instantiation, and method invocation.

Comment: @Bergi, I completely agree.